# Can i make a reflexive association and normal association

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database

My title is not as specific as it should because i do not really know how to formulate it.

Ok, so what i'am wondering is : can i or not create in a relational model something as shown in the picture. 
I want to do that to generate a primary key with two identifiers from the boat table (*In order to have the attacker ID and the attacked boat ID*) and the pirate identifier. That's will perfectly do what i want when i translate it to the logical model using JMerise. But is it a correct relational model ? 
[Relational Model using JMerise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YlmqU.jpg)  & 
[Logical Model using JMerise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dL5aN.jpg)

Thanks all.

Comment: Without your functional requirements, it's impossible to judge your models. Your second model looks as if an action concerned exactly one pirate and exactly two boats. If that's what you want to express, it's okay. In my naive understanding, an action would comprise one or more pirates, and mostly just one boat (unless you count the pirate's boat). I don't see either what should be relexive here, as neither the boats, the pirates, or the actions, point to themselves.

Comment: Thanks Tam for your answer,
Actually what i am trying to represent is a pirate attacking a boat with one of his boats. 
My use of the word reflexive is not correct i guess, Like i said i didn't knew really how to post my question without my two models.
I'll stick with your answer and hopefully my teacher will agree with this view.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just one pirate and one attacked boat on each action, then it depends on whether the pirate always uses the same boat or not. If the pirate may change boats, then you'll have

```
pirate 1----0,n action 0,n--attacked--1 boat
                   |                     |
                   |0,n----attacking--1--|
```

If the pirate always uses the same boat, it would be

```
pirate 1----0,n action 0,n--attacked--1 boat
  |                                      |
  |0,1---------------------attacking--1--|
```

Mind the cardinalities, I think in your diagram they were the wrong way round.

Comment: I have multiple pirates with multiple boats attacking multiple players boats in the same game.